# Getting token from Microsoft.​Service​Bus Token​Provider

Tags: c#, azure-eventhub

I looked through all the available resources and docs but couldn't figure out what **action** parameter signifies in Token​Provider.​Get​Token​Async Method. 
Is there a specific string constant that I need to pass ?

[Reference to the method in learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.tokenprovider.gettokenasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_TokenProvider_GetTokenAsync_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_System_TimeSpan_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I got no answers here (and if it might be useful for someone in future), I am quoting the answer that i got for my question in msdn forum:

"Technically any string can be passed as action. A short, meaningful string would be better. That action is used as a part of the key in the token cache." - Sheethal J S

link:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/483204ef-7788-4ceb-99d2-dc86e17c9967/getting-token-from-microsoftservicebus-tokenprovider?forum=servbus